# Dynamically created HTML elements don't work with event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, event-listener

In short, I wanted to implement drag and drop in my chess (like you can drag chess pieces). But something is wrong.

**Problem:**
The dynamically created chess piece (the one to the right) has the required event listener in its property lists, since I first dynamically create it, and only then add an event listener to each. But it doesn't work. For example, I put another chess piece (the one on the left) created in html. And everything works on it.

[Problem preview (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igd4V.png)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="chess_field">
        <button class="place" id="place11">
            <div class="figure wp" id="" draggable="true"></div>
        </button>
        <button class="place" id="place12">
        </button>
        <button class="place" id="place13">
        </button>
        <button class="place" id="place14">
        </button>
        <button class="place" id="place15">
        </button>
        <button class="place" id="place16">
        </button>
        <button class="place" id="place17">
        </button>
        <button class="place" id="place18">
        </button>
    </div>
    <script defer src="scripts_ui.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JavsScript:**

```
let chessField = [[0, 0, 0, "wp", 0, 0, 0, 0]];

let dragged_element;

function DragEventAdd() {
    let figure = window.document.querySelectorAll(".figure");
    figure = Array.from(figure);
    figure.map((f) => {
        f.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
            console.log("drag started");
        });
    });
}

function arrangeFigures() {
    chessField.map((i, y) => {i.map((j, x) => {
            if (j !== 0) {
                let place = window.document.getElementById(`place${y+1}${x+1}`);
                let figure = document.createElement("div");
                figure.classList.add("figure");
                figure.classList.add(j);
                figure.setAttribute("graggable", true);
                place.appendChild(figure);
            }
        })});
        debugger;
    DragEventAdd();
}

let place_drop = window.document.querySelectorAll(".place");
    place_drop = Array.from(place_drop);
    place_drop.map((pd) => {
        pd.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
            dragged_element = "";
        });
    });
arrangeFigures();
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chess_field {
  width: 80vh;
  height: 80vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.place {
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
}

.figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.wp {
  background-image: url(img/wp.png);
}
```

**Code description:**
The variable "chessField" is a two-dimensional array containing information about where the chess pieces are.

"arrageFigures" function - deals with adding chess pieces to cells with "place" classes.

Function "DragEventAdd" - **ADDS EVENT LISTENERS TO THEM.**

I rummaged through the entire StackOverflow, and all the problems associated with this were caused by the fact that people did not give event listeners to newly created elements. But that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: `figure.setAttribute("graggable", true);`  is that just a copy paste typo?

Comment: OH MY GOD! I've been puzzling over this for two weeks now. Discussed it with the teacher. We sat and did not notice it. How stupid is that. I sincerely thank you. Now everything works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quick fix

```js
function arrangeFigures() {
    chessField.map((i, y) => {
        i.map((j, x) => {
            if (j !== 0) {
                let place = window.document.getElementById(`place${y+1}${x+1}`);
                let figure = document.createElement("div");
                figure.classList.add("figure");
                figure.classList.add(j);
                figure.setAttribute("draggable", true);
                place.appendChild(figure);
            }
        });
    });

    DragEventAdd();
}
```

Comment: now dynamic elements  is dargable

Comment: OH MY GOD! I've been puzzling over this for two weeks now. Discussed it with the teacher. We sat and did not notice it. How stupid is that. I sincerely thank you.